# Python problema con append de open()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estaba escribiendo un código que verifique que una palabra no exista en un archivo, y si existe que me diga que ya existe pero si no, que lo agregue, les comparto el código:

```
def appendWords():
    confirmation = input("Do you want to add the found word to the wordlist? [Y/n]: ")
    if confirmation.lower() == "yes" or confirmation.lower() == "y":
        confirm_wordlist = input("\nEnter the path of the wordlist: ")
        with open(confirm_wordlist, "a+") as r:
            wordlist_ = [] #Lista donde se guardara las palabras limpias de saltos de linea
            for n in r:
                wordlist_.append(n.strip()) #Limpia la lista de los saltos de linea

            for k in wordlist_: #Bucle donde checkeara si esa palabra ya existe en en el archivo
                if not i in wordlist_: # Checkear si la palabra (i) no existe en el archivo 
                    r.write("\n"+i)     # Si no existe que lo agrege
                    print(f"Word added to the wordlist: {confirm_wordlist}")
                    sys.exit(0)
                else:  # Si ya existe que me lo haga saber
                    print("That word already exists in the wordlist")
                    sys.exit(1)
    else: # Si se ingreso un input diferente a "y" o "yes" que salga 
        print("Okay...")
        sys.exit(0)
```

el problema esta en el append, ya que cuando hago uso de el no entra en el bucle for, solo corre hasta el input, pero cuando llega al **"for n in r:"** y al **"for k in wordlist_:"** no lo cumple, es como si lo ignorara, por lo que probé con el **"r+"**
y ahí si funcionan los bucles, la verdad no se por qué pasa eso con el **"a+"**, verifique si solo era porque no entraba en el with open pero si entra, llega hasta la lista wordlist_, pero de ahí no avanza... si alguien lo sabe por qué pasa esto que por favor me lo diga, ya lo busque en internet y no encontré nada, de ante mano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para comenzar, abrirlo con modo `"a+"` es exactamente igual que abrirlo con modo `"a"`, el `+` no tiene ningún efecto aquí.

El problema es que estás abriendo el archivo en modo *append*, y luego intentas leer sobre él, pero el *puntero del archivo* está posicionado al final del del mismo, además que ya se encuentra en modo de escritura.

Y es que *append* significa justamente eso: **abrir el archivo en modo escritura con el puntero posicionado al final**, que es lo que permite *agregarle* contenido.

Si quieres abrirlo, leer su contenido y, al final, agregar información, entonces ábrelo en modo `r+`.

Más información en la [documentación de *open()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).